# Windows Firewall: MMC could not create the snap-in

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows

On Windows Server 2008 when trying to open either Event Viewer or Windows Firewall settings, I'm getting the following error:

> MMC could not create the snap-in. The snap-in might not have been
>   installed correctly.
>   Name: Windows Firewall with Advanced Security
>   CLSID: FX: {b05566ac-fe9c-4368-be02-7a4cbb7cbe11}

Answer (score 1):

Had this same error, had to ring Microsoft support to get it worked out. Had to install kb2688730 to resolve the issue.

The KB article for kb2688730 doesn't address the error message but it does resolve the issue (have done this on 20+ 2008R2 boxes now).

The cause was as follows: As far as we can tell, either the patch installation on the affected servers was interrupted in some way, or did not complete properly, causing .Net corruption on the servers.

Comment: does not apply error http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?/files/file/14681-windows61-kb2688730-x64msu/&do=download&csrfKey=2671cf1b97150a82b110a9df2d7643ca

Answer (score -1):

Seems that there are some snapins/dll corrupted ...

Have you tried to run a scandisk  ?  (`sfc /scannow`)

if the scandisk doesn't resolve the problem try registering the snapins dll :

1. Open a command prompt with administrative privileges
2. Copy and paste the following commands into the elevated command prompt, or you can save the commands into a batch file, and then execute the batch script:

   `regsvr32 /s adprop.dll
   regsvr32 /s azroles.dll
   regsvr32 /s azroleui.dll
   regsvr32 /s ccfg95.dll
   regsvr32 /s certadm.dll
   regsvr32 /s certmmc.dll
   regsvr32 /s certpdef.dll
   regsvr32 /s certtmpl.dll
   regsvr32 /s certxds.dll
   regsvr32 /s cladmwiz.dll
   regsvr32 /s clcfgsrv.dll
   regsvr32 /s clnetrex.dll
   regsvr32 /s cluadmex.dll
   regsvr32 /s cluadmmc.dll
   regsvr32 /s cmproxy.dll
   regsvr32 /s cmroute.dll
   regsvr32 /s cmutoa.dll
   regsvr32 /s cnet16.dll
   regsvr32 /s debugex.dll
   regsvr32 /s dfscore.dll
   regsvr32 /s dfsgui.dll
   regsvr32 /s dhcpsnap.dll
   regsvr32 /s dnsmgr.dll
   regsvr32 /s domadmin.dll
   regsvr32 /s dsadmin.dll
   regsvr32 /s dsuiwiz.dll
   regsvr32 /s imadmui.dll
   regsvr32 /s lrwizdll.dll
   regsvr32 /s mprsnap.dll
   regsvr32 /s msclus.dll
   regsvr32 /s mstsmhst.dll
   regsvr32 /s mstsmmc.dll
   regsvr32 /s nntpadm.dll
   regsvr32 /s nntpapi.dll
   regsvr32 /s nntpsnap.dll
   regsvr32 /s ntdsbsrv.dll
   regsvr32 /s ntfrsapi.dll
   regsvr32 /s rasuser.dll
   regsvr32 /s rigpsnap.dll
   regsvr32 /s rsadmin.dll
   regsvr32 /s rscommon.dll
   regsvr32 /s rsconn.dll
   regsvr32 /s rsengps.dll
   regsvr32 /s rsjob.dll
   regsvr32 /s rsservps.dll
   regsvr32 /s rsshell.dll
   regsvr32 /s rssubps.dll
   regsvr32 /s rtrfiltr.dll
   regsvr32 /s schmmgmt.dll
   regsvr32 /s tapisnap.dll
   regsvr32 /s tsuserex.dll
   regsvr32 /s uddi.mmc.dll
   regsvr32 /s vsstskex.dll
   regsvr32 /s w95inf16.dll
   regsvr32 /s w95inf32.dll
   regsvr32 /s winsevnt.dll
   regsvr32 /s winsmon.dll
   regsvr32 /s winsrpc.dll
   regsvr32 /s winssnap.dll
   regsvr32 /s ws03res.dll`

I've resolved one time a similar error on windows server 2003 with this procedure.

Comment: Just running a huge number of regsvr-commands blindly does not seem like a safe resolution.

Comment: Does not alter Snap-ins

Answer (score -2):

1. Open control pannel
2. Add/remove programs
3. Locate Microsoft .NET framework
4. Right click, choose uninstall/change
5. Microsoft .NET window will pop up
6. Click repair.

Done!

Comment: .NET is not a prerequisite for these MMC's and thus these steps are moot.

Comment: .NET4.8 Does not even read registry Snap-ins during repair  but was relevant for .NET2 rollup  with kb2688730